# About the Stochastic Volterra equation driven by the Gaussian white noise

Tags: probability

I need your help please.
Suppose that we have a stochastic integral equation shaping as follows.
$$ X_{t} + \int_{0}^{t}k(t-s)X_{s}ds = \overset{\bullet}{B}_{t}, \quad t > 0$$ and $$ X_{t} = U(t), \quad t \leq 0.$$
Here $K$ is positive deterministe kernel, $\overset{\bullet}{B}_{t}$ is the time derivativative (in the sense of distributions) of the Browian motion $B_{t}$ and $U$ is a given non stochastic function.
What I knows sofar is that $\overset{\bullet}{B}_{t} \in (S)^{*}$ the space of Hida distributions. I would like to analyse the well posedness (and an explicit solution) to this equation. But I don't find any reference talking about this: that is the reason why I decided to ask for help to the communitee.